# Insert Into syntax Error importing data from excel

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I need some help with a short query I have been having some trouble with a query I am writing to update a table based on data on a excel sheet but keep running into a syntax error

```
INSERT INTO  [Fleet Commit] ([Commit Type], [Sales Column], [Column1], No, Gender, Style, [Style Descr], Short, [Product Line], Color, Team, [Team Code], Color2, [Logo 1], [Place 1], [Logo 2], [Place 2], [Logo 3], [Place 3], [Logo 4], [Place 4], [Size Scale], [Case Ratio], [Case Ratio Total], [Different Case Ratio], [Approved Whsl], [Suggested Retail], [Customer Whsl], [Customer Retail], [Master Packed? (Y)], [UPC by Size (S) or Carton (C)?], [Solid SKU (S)/ Ratio (R )], [Total Units], [Case Qty], [Total $$], [SAMPLE QTY], [SAMPLE SIZE], [IMAGE REQUEST Y/N], [Licensing Samples])
FROM (SELECT [Commit Type], [Sales Column], [Column1], No, Gender, Style, [Style Descr], Short, [Product Line], Color, Team, [Team Code], Color2, [Logo 1], [Place 1], [Logo 2], [Place 2], [Logo 3], [Place 3], [Logo 4], [Place 4], [Size Scale], [Case Ratio], [Case Ratio Total], [Different Case Ratio], [Approved Whsl], [Suggested Retail], [Customer Whsl], [Customer Retail], [Master Packed? (Y)], [UPC by Size (S) or Carton (C)?], [Solid SKU (S)/ Ratio (R )], [Total Units], [Case Qty], [Total $$], [SAMPLE QTY], [SAMPLE SIZE], [IMAGE REQUEST Y/N], [Licensing Samples]
FROM [Fleet Commit]
IN SCDesktop\Retail SA Fall 19 Master Commit Document - 12062018\Retail SA Fall 19 Master Commit Document - 12062018.xlsx" "EXCEL 5.0;"
GROUP BY  [Commit Type], [Sales Column], [Column1], [No], Gender, Style, [Style Descr], Short, [Product Line], Color, Team, [Team Code], Color2, [Logo 1], [Place 1], [Logo 2], [Place 2], [Logo 3], [Place 3], [Logo 4], [Place 4], [Size Scale], [Case Ratio], [Case Ratio Total], [Different Case Ratio], [Approved Whsl], [Suggested Retail], [Customer Whsl], [Customer Retail], [Master Packed? (Y)], [UPC by Size (S) or Carton (C)?], [Solid SKU (S)/ Ratio (R )], [Total Units], [Case Qty], [Total $$], [SAMPLE QTY], [SAMPLE SIZE], [IMAGE REQUEST Y/N], [Licensing Samples]
ORDER BY  Style);
```

Comment: From what I can see, you're missing an opening quote on that file path and it's not a valid path. There might be more errors, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in this line:

```
IN SCDesktop\Retail SA Fall 19 Master Commit Document - 12062018\Retail SA Fall 19 Master Commit Document - 12062018.xlsx"
```

You should also remove the first FROM clause, it's not a part of INSERT INTO command, as well as ORDER BY. Shall be something like:

```
INSERT INTO [Fleet Commit] ([Commit Type], [Sales Column], [Column1], No, Gender, Style, [Style Descr], Short, [Product Line], Color, Team, [Team Code], Color2, [Logo 1], [Place 1], [Logo 2], [Place 2], [Logo 3], [Place 3], [Logo 4], [Place 4], [Size Scale], [Case Ratio], [Case Ratio Total], [Different Case Ratio], [Approved Whsl], [Suggested Retail], [Customer Whsl], [Customer Retail], [Master Packed? (Y)], [UPC by Size (S) or Carton (C)?], [Solid SKU (S)/ Ratio (R )], [Total Units], [Case Qty], [Total $$], [SAMPLE QTY], [SAMPLE SIZE], [IMAGE REQUEST Y/N], [Licensing Samples])
SELECT [Commit Type], [Sales Column], [Column1], No, Gender, Style, [Style Descr], Short, [Product Line], Color, Team, [Team Code], Color2, [Logo 1], [Place 1], [Logo 2], [Place 2], [Logo 3], [Place 3], [Logo 4], [Place 4], [Size Scale], [Case Ratio], [Case Ratio Total], [Different Case Ratio], [Approved Whsl], [Suggested Retail], [Customer Whsl], [Customer Retail], [Master Packed? (Y)], [UPC by Size (S) or Carton (C)?], [Solid SKU (S)/ Ratio (R )], [Total Units], [Case Qty], [Total $$], [SAMPLE QTY], [SAMPLE SIZE], [IMAGE REQUEST Y/N], [Licensing Samples]
    FROM [Excel 5.0;HDR=Yes;Database=you file path here].[Sheet1$]
    GROUP BY  [Commit Type], [Sales Column], [Column1], [No], Gender, Style, [Style Descr], Short, [Product Line], Color, Team, [Team Code], Color2, [Logo 1], [Place 1], [Logo 2], [Place 2], [Logo 3], [Place 3], [Logo 4], [Place 4], [Size Scale], [Case Ratio], [Case Ratio Total], [Different Case Ratio], [Approved Whsl], [Suggested Retail], [Customer Whsl], [Customer Retail], [Master Packed? (Y)], [UPC by Size (S) or Carton (C)?], [Solid SKU (S)/ Ratio (R )], [Total Units], [Case Qty], [Total $$], [SAMPLE QTY], [SAMPLE SIZE], [IMAGE REQUEST Y/N], [Licensing Samples];
```

Comment: I updated the quoatation but I am still getting a syntax error

Comment: It says it too long its the same code plus the missing quotation added.

Comment: I received the error."Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement".

Comment: I have updated the query and I am still getting the same error. Also how should I format the sheet name if the name is  [Fleet Commit]

Comment: It keeps highlighting my short field with this error. But I do not see what could be wrong

Comment: Put the highlighted field name in brackes [ ]

Comment: And the sheet name in FROM clause should be formatted like [Fleet Commit$] - ending with $.